# Jest failing to run test including a reference to a .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

When I try to run a test that is including a reference to a .d.ts file I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/tests/IlsfpSeries.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'app/core/time_series2' from 'IlssppSeries.ts'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './IlssppSeries.ts'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'].
```

This is what is causing the error (in IlssppSeries.ts):

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/grafana-sdk-mocks/app/headers/common.d.ts" />

import TimeSeries from "app/core/time_series2";
```

I have the following line in my jest.config.js file. I have tried some variants of the path, without success.

```
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    'app/core/time_series2': './node_modules/grafana-sdk-mocks/app/headers/common.d.ts',
  },
```

It works fine in typescript, it's just the testing that isn't working. Any ideas?

I have made a small repository that can reproduce the issue: 
[Mini repository](https://github.com/jimbom/panel)